# Monitoring file changes in Linux with older glibc

Tags: c, glibc, inotify, fstat

I need to monitor events on a regular file using file descriptors. I'm working on a machine with CentOS 4.1, and kernel version 2.6.18.128.

After realizing that regular file cannot be monitored using `epoll`, I found this task can be accomplished using `inotify`. However, I read elsewhere that the required library interfaces for `inotify` were added to glibc in version 2.4, and my machine has version 2.3.4 installed. So my kernel has inotify support by not glibc. Unfortunately, I *cannot* update glibc to a newer version because it would break certain other parts of the project.

So my questions are:

1. Can I still use `inotify` to monitor regular file? Could I get a newer version of glibc and place it at a local folder(relative to my code), include the path in my Makefile and use calls associated with `inotify`? If so, what kind of problems could I run into?
2. An alternative could be using `fstat`, by keeping track of the `st_mtime` member of the `struct stat` structure. Any caveats against taking this route?

If my questions reveal any lack of understanding with these concepts please bear with me as I just started using them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 2 glibc see the following post:
   [Multiple glibc libraries on a single host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847179/multiple-glibc-libraries-on-a-single-host)

Otherwise inotify seems straight forward solution.

Comment: Thanks for the link! One clarification as I'm still confused on a certain point. Other parts of the project I'm contributing to will be using the older glibc, where as I'm the only one who needs the newer version. Can I use two different versions of glib for building  a single project? Will this not cause some issues?

Comment: Well do you have any specific functionality that require older glibc? You can not link against 2 different library versions it will be ambigous condition for the compiler.

Comment: Just to add you can have 2 different linked applications and controll the calls via ifdef MACRO with GLIBC version.

Comment: Yes there are many functionalities that require the older glibc. One of us tried using the newer glibc once but it gave a lot of errors at runtime, which will take time to sort out. This is why I need both libraries simultaneously. So fstat is my best bet then?

Comment: If your application is a seperate one You can easily use different glibc by just fixing header files an librariers path otherwise fsstat is the way to go.